# How To Add JLabel to Already Existing Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jlabel

lol i dont even know if i worded that right

i am a really new programmer and this is my code for the main class:

package culminatingnew;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JTextField;


 public class CulminatingNew {



public static void main(String[] args) {


 Container container = null;


JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Math Adventure");
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
jframe.setBounds (150, 0, 1000, 1000);
jframe.setBackground(Color.blue);
jframe.setVisible(true);


 JLabel labelText = new JLabel("Welcome!");        

 jframe.getContentPane().add(new CharacterChoose());//
 jframe.setVisible(true);
 jframe.getContentPane().add(labelText); 
 jframe.setVisible(true);
```

So basically, I'm making a game. In another class in the assignment package is CharacterChoose, where the user is greeted with a picture of their character. All I want to do is add text to this same screen saying "Welcome", but whenever I try this it just ignores the CharacterChoose screen and opens a new blank frame that says "Welcome". Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

GUI's are not linear/procedural programs, the are event driven, that is, something happens and you respond to it.

Instead, maybe consider using a button saying "Continue" or something, which the user must press, once pressed, you can then present the next view.

I'd recommend having a look at `CardLayout` for easier management of switching between views.

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: I'd also add the Layout manager link (I can't post link by now) but OP can search it as "Java Layout Manager" in Google or through Card Layout page too